# Первые шаги в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

На основе [стандартного примера](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart) пробую реализовать корзину покупок. В некоторых местах сразу же возникло не понимание.

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Что за магическая конструкция `render: h => h(App)`? Правильно ли я понимаю, что если мы записываем в таком виде, то нам не нужно указывать компонент в `app.blade.php`? На следующем этапе я планируется подключить Vne Router. Не сыграет ли такой подход мне во вред?

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

Опять не понятно. Если указать `<ProductList><ProductList/>`, то будет [ошибка](http://ssmaker.ru/7a2b29a1.jpg), а вот так `<ProductList/>` - работает. Если не трудно, то помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Одно дело сделать так чтобы это работало, другое понимать как это работает. Спасибо.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ProductList/>
        <ShoppingCart/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ProductList from './ProductList.vue'
    import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            ProductList,
            ShoppingCart
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Правильно, вы сообщаете vuejs, что компонент `App` является корневым. Он должен будет содержать в себе `<router-view>` для работы с `vue-route`. Далее при загрузке страницы приложение заинжектится по селектору #app.

2) Это не может никак влиять на ошибку. Правила именования не нарушены. 
Короткий вариант `<ProductList/>` используется если компонент не нуждается во входных параметрах. 
UPD: у вас ошибка действительно. Закрывающий слэш должен быть перед началом селектора.

```
<ProductList></ProductList>
```

Можно самостоятельно задавать нужный вам селектор

```
<script>
    import ProductList from './ProductList.vue'
    import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            'product-list':ProductList,
            'shopping-cart': ShoppingCart
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ошибка - http://ssmaker.ru/7a2b29a1/

Comment: Ах, да. Закрывающий слэш должен быть в начале имени
<ProductList></ProductList>

Answer (score 0):

Можно и не именовать компоненты

```js
<script>
    import ProductList from './ProductList.vue'
    import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            ProductList,
            ShoppingCart
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div>

<product-list></product-list>
<shopping-cart></shopping-cart>

</div>
</template>
```